# Check a byte's value in python

Tags: python, image, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to read jpg image data coming in from serial port in byte format.  Since jpg starts with FF/D8 and ends with FF/D9 I'm thinking I should read each byte value coming in and start/stop writing the bytes to a file if it's 1 of those values?  Is this the best way to do this?  If so how do I check for the byte value?

```
import serial
import sys

outf = open("image1.jpg", 'w')


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)

while True:
    c = ser.read() # reading a byte here
    #check c for FF/D8 or FF/D9?
    if c == ?
        #write to file here?
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Can you test whether `ord(c) == 255`? If that works, but you want to be able to use hexadecimal, wrap `hex()` around it.

Comment: Yes ord works I will try that thanks.